# How to addClass() at RANDOM to an element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The html/css:

```
<style>
div.myWords p { display: hidden; }
p.show { display: block; }
</style>

<div class="myWords">

<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hola</p>
<p>Bonjour</p>

</div><!-- myWords -->
```

How can I add the class "show" to a single `<p>` element at a time at random on document ready?

In other words, every time the page is loaded 1 p tag should be visible and this p tag should be chosen at random.

Comment: Note that it's `display: none`, not `display: hidden`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var paras = $('div.myWords p');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
    paras.eq(rand).addClass('show');
});
```

If you are trying to change `display: none` to `display: block`, you can omit the `show` class from your CSS and show it using only jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var paras = $('div.myWords p');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
    paras.eq(rand).show();
});
```

By the way, you need to change your CSS so that overrides work. Change `display: hidden;` to `display: none;`, and add the `div.myWords` class to your second rule:

```
div.myWords p { display: none; }
div.myWords p.show { display: block; }
```